# Ubuntu 18.04 Freezing on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, lenovo, 18.04, uid

I have a Lenovo T60 and everytime I try to boot 18.04 it gets to "Starting user manager for UID 121" on the boot screen it freezes then the mouse arrow comes up. This is massive bug exclusive to 18.04. On  17.10 and 16.04 everything is fine Ive purged and reinstalled every form of nvidia, purged and reinstalled nouveau as well as upgraded GRUB more than I can count.. I am currently typing this question in recovery mode. Thats the only way I can get it to work. I wonder if its a 32/64 bit issue. For windows its 64 bit but for linux I can only do 32 bit.

Comment: I have a similar problem.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was bionic beaver is for 64 bit only. even though bionic beaver was the one that shows up on your updater.  you need to get ubuntu budgie thats the 18.04 build for 32 bit. Im guessing the developers figured it wasnt worth the effort being more open about that fact.

Comment: https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads

Comment: In my case, it's not a 32-bit problem. Isn't your Lenovo 64-bit? See my details at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot-need-video-kernel-parameter

Comment: No its a 32 bit its a i686 so its only 64 bit for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved same case: Lenovo T60 ubuntu 18.04 boot stops.

Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and un-comment:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```