# Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Boot on Battery Power

Tags: boot, 18.04

Older Acer Aspire laptop with i3 processor.  Ubuntu loads fine when plugged in wall, but won't boot with only battery power.  I see the Acer splash with bios information, but it turns off before ever seeing the purple Ubuntu boot up screen.  Had no problems with Ubuntu 16.x.  Laptop recently got new battery.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

[This link](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/m-p/7523968#M3185) worked for my HP laptop.

1) Modify the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` kernel variable in */etc/default/grub*:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"
```

2) `$ sudo update-grub`

3) Reboot.

`dis_ucode_ldr` stands for "disable microcode loader"

Comment: This save my life on Dell 7530

Answer (score 0):

## Update

That didn't fix things :/
I have noticed that the power state on shutdown, affects whether I get a freeze on boot. If the power states are not the same (AC / Battery), then I get a freeze on boot...

## Update

I fixed this issue using the following solution:

edit the `sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file by uncommenting the following line:

`WaylandEnable=false`

save and restart

Helped by this link [Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on booting with message "started user manager for uid 120" on Asus 1015PX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037922/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-on-booting-with-message-started-user-manager-for-uid-120-on)

Don't have enough points to leave a comment.

I have the same issue

Ubuntu 18.04

kernel v4.18.14

I have a Dell xps-15 i7 9570

which is known to have issues with Ubuntu, which required me to add the acpi override option to grub, as well as disabling nouveau.

Suspect it's an ACPI issue, or a graphics card - power managament issue...if that isn't the same thing...

I have the following in my `/etc/default/grub` file:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash nouveau.modeset=0 i8042.nopnp irqpoll acpi_rev_override=1"`

Boots fine if on AC power.
freezes at splash screen if booting from battery power.

Any help would be great.

Going to try kernel v4.18.16 or possibly v4.19 (using Ukuu-gtk)
and removing the acpi_rev_override=1 from grub.
Just building up the courage first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop and I solved the problem by updating the Linux kernel to the last version and setting the grub config as mentioned by Colin Anthony.