# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot up on laptop when running on battery

Tags: boot, 20.04, battery

## Situation

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new HP 17-ca1124ng laptop.

Unfortunately, however, I realized that the OS will boot **only** when the laptop is charging. When trying to boot Ubuntu without having the laptop on a charger, I am asked to decrypt the hard drive (which works) but then the boot process just hangs on a black screen. Booting while on charger, then disconnecting from the charger works perfectly fine.

## Resolution attempts

- new install of Ubuntu 20.04 did not cut it
- BIOS reset did not cut it
- changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/grub/default` to

  - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"` and running `sudo update-grub` did not cut it
  - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"` and running `sudo update-grub` to maybe get some info on what fails but everything is flagged as `OK` during boot

## Questions

1. Is this a hardware or software issue?
2. If this is software related, how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

## Similar issues

- [Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot on battery power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061270/ubuntu-18-04-wont-boot-on-battery-power)
- [Dell Forum discussion on laptops only booting Linux is charger is connected](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/td-p/7449042)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your **/etc/default/grub** as such

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash iommu=soft”
```

don't forget to...

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Might be of interest for those running Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell computers:

I had the same problem on a Dell Latitude 7300 and the accepted answer did not work for me, however the [answer](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/m-p/7523968#M3185) from the Dell community forum mentioned in the original post did work:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: This worked for me, I have a Latitude 5400