# Ubuntu 22.04 - Notebook doesnt boot up when running on battery

Tags: boot, power-management, battery, 22.04

I have this problem for a long while after the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 in my notebook. If I’m working on it, plugged to electricity, and unplug it to emulate an outage, I can keep working perfectly fine, running my notebook on batteries [this dismisses the potential issue of having damaged batteries]. However, **when it’s turned off, and I try to boot it up, running on batteries** [unplugged from the electricity] **it won’t respond. It doesn’t even start.** By this, I mean that even the usual light in the power button doesn't even start, screen stays black, there are no lights and no fans.
This never happened before when I had Ubuntu 20.04 on this notebook. It started after the installation of Ubuntu 22.04, sadly.

I’ve tried already these solutions [[here]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268804/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-boot-up-on-laptop-when-running-on-battery), but none worked. [I tried the suggestion for Dell computers even when my notebooks is not of that brand].
I also awaited several updates in hopes that it would be fixed with some update in case the problem was a bug in the new system. But so far, I found no solution to this problem.

The info of my notebook is the following:

The brand is a national one: Kanji Tamura, intel dual core 847.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM70 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
01:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Keep in mind I’m not an expert in computers or Ubuntu.
[I also apologise for any weird expression I may use in the explanation, I'm not a native English speaker]

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion.

Edit: Following Esther's answer, I'll assume it must be a hardware problem, even though it starts perfectly fine when it's plugged, or when once it's turned on, I unplug it and keeps working without problems.

Comment: how far does it get before booting? This sounds like a hardware/UEFI issue, since it is happening before you ever get to Ubuntu.

Comment: some people suggest removing the laptop battery for like 15 minutes, then putting it back together. This can also help you see if the CMOS battery is failing: boot into the BIOS after leaving the battery out for 15 minutes; if the date and time in BIOS is wrong your CMOS battery might be dying.

Comment: how far does it get it booting? if it *doesn't respond at all* (screen stays black, no lights or fans) it's definitely a hardware issue, if it turns on but doesn't get very far, it may be a software issue

Comment: I was trying the option of the 15 min. But it's as you said:   it doesn't respond at all : screen stays black, there is no lights and no fans. I don't understand how this can be a hardware problem when it starts perfectly fine when it's plugged, or when once it's turned on, I unplug it and keeps working without problems. Anyways, thank you very much, I suppose I will send it to a technician in this case.

Comment: I've just finished with the procedure of removing the battery of the notebook for 15 min, and booting it up. It keeps the date and the hour correctly.