# Not booting - Failed to start user manager for uid 121

Tags: boot

My Ubuntu 18.04.4 won't start.
It goes into a black screen where it tries to start User Manager for UID 121
And then display the message:

```
Failed to start User Manager for UID 121 
See 'systemctl status user@121.service' for details.
```

I managed to access the desktop through recovery mode but it happens at each start-up now.
I tried *Repair Broken packages* but does not not fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037922/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-on-booting-with-message-started-user-manager-for-uid-120-on

Comment: No, i have tried these solutions but still not working

Comment: `getent passwd  | grep 121`

Comment: I ended up re-installing ubuntu. Thanks anyway.