# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot, hangs at "Stopping User Manager for UID 120..."

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia

I have a Dell Precision 5820 Tower that shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 to which I added a dual boot of Windows 10. It has a Nvidia Geforce 3090. After some faff getting Windows installed on top of Ubuntu and repairing the grub boot menu, both were working well for a while. However I tried to boot the computer today into Ubuntu and it hung on a black screen with some text, the last line being:

> Stopping User Manager for UID 120

I rebooted into Ubuntu recovery mode and tried the "clean: Try to make free space" and "dpkg Repair broken packages" options. Neither helped. I can select root "Drop to root shell prompt" to potentially try and repair things there but do not know what I'm doing. I'd really like to avoid reinstalling everything if at all possible.

An hour of googling the closest I found was this issue: [Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on booting with message "started user manager for uid 120" on Asus 1015PX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037922/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-on-booting-with-message-started-user-manager-for-uid-120-on)
But there seem to be numerous complicated suggestions and it is not clear which, if any, could help here.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to start a virtual console from the freeze page
following [17.10 to 18.04 upgrade freezes during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot/1037192#1037192) but it then flickers rapidly back and forth between the console and the freeze page making it impossible to type username and password in correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text include all text in the body of the question. I have seen this problem when windows was not fully shut down or not shut down properly. Start windows, does it run without errors.

Comment: Thanks, edited question to remove image of text. Just checked again and windows boots and runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had another go at it and was able to boot it up after trying [17.10 to 18.04 upgrade freezes during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot/1037192#1037192) the switch to lightdm option.
No idea what caused the problem.