# Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 but stuck to loading screen

Tags: boot, upgrade, compatibility

So I have a laptop which is somehow old, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it and after a couple of months, v18.04 is released. I decided to upgrade mine to 18.04 but after downloading and installing on my laptop, it is now stuck on the Ubuntu startup/loading screen (after restart), I thought it is just like that but it stayed like that for an hour and a half. I checked their website to see their compatibility requirements and it met except for the needed 2.0Ghz, mine is 1.5-8Ghz but I think it is not the problem because it runs the v16.04 fine.
Download/File integrity is also good.

Can it not really run on my laptop because of the GHz difference? or something?

- Intel Core 2 Duo Processor
- Currently Running Windows 7 Pro x32
- 3GB System Memory
- 111 Hard Drive Space
- Wireless Internet Access

Comment: It does not solved mine, anyway it is probably because of unsupported graphics card. thanks anyway for the link.

Comment: See my question/answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot, update #7, for a possible fix. Please remember to vote if it's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @karel this question is not a dup, but rather a 18.04 bug for computers with older Intel video subsystems. See my previous comment.