# Ubuntu 18.04 graphics issue

Tags: graphics, 18.04, fglrx

How do I handle Ubuntu 18.04 not handling fglrx ? There was no problem in 16.04 & 14.04.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and now the monitor ends up flashing as it tries to load gdm3. The tty screens too were flashing, i.e. after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/.../<kbd>F7</kbd> I still got the flashing screen forwarding in the GDM monitor. It was too difficult to handle anything in any consoles mode. I see [this link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/fglrx-installer) which says:

> There is no current release of this source package in The Bionic Beaver. You can still report bugs, make translations, and so on, but they might not be used until the package is published.

How should I handle the proprietary graphics driver issue?

If possible, is there a way I could revert back to 16.04 ?

Also...

Was it too early ( 5 July 2018 )  for me to upgrade to 18.04 ? 14.04 handled this issue perfectly, 16.04 created occasionally overheating ( in Sublime Text 3 ) so I upgraded to18.04 expecting to have the issue solved.

I am using Dell Inspiron 15r having i7.

Comment: Maybe the graphics driver is still OK in 18.04 and the real problem is loading gdm3 login display manager. If you want to investigate this possibility try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot/1037192#1037192

Comment: The tty screens too were flashing. ie. after Ctrl+Shift+F1/.../F7 I still got the flashing screen forwarding in ihe GDM  monitor. It was too difficult to handle anything in any consols mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about fglrx being available or not, but I just solved a similar issue.

First, to get rid of the annoying flashing screen, I configured lightdm instead of gdm3. You can either do this by booting into recovery mode from grub (hold shift from when you see the BIOS if it doesnt show by default), or type on the terminal in between the flashes / X starting attempts. You'll have to:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Reboot and hopefully lightdm will show up. The desktop still wasn't working for me, but at least you can normally do something on the commandline now.

Secondly, I ran 'sudo apt-get upgrade' and noticed some graphics related packages held back. This could be resolved in a rather crude way:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I did some other stuff, but I think the above is what resolved my issue. You can also see if the stuff in karel's link helps you.