# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS support for Intel Core M Processor

Tags: 18.04, xorg, lightdm, gdm, wayland

I never installed a `Ubuntu Desktop` on `Intel Core M` processor before and not even on current laptop. I am trying out Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am facing non-smooth animations of app drawer and stuttering of UI. I came from windows 7 and laptop was working super fast with aero enabled.

**System Details**
**Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS**
[image]

**Wayland vs Xorg & Lightdm vs gdm3**
I dig a little bit and found that there can be issues with wayland/xorg or lightdm/gdm3 configurations. I read in a [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086935) that wayland doesnot support old driver hence, switching back to xorg would fix the issue.
Another article point out to use open source drivers in wayland configuration because vendor drivers does not support wayland as it is pre-mature right now.

**System Monitor**
In anther thread it was suggested to remove system monitor as It was causing stuttering. I checked my cpu usage and it was 100% for 1 core. So, I removed it.

**Remove xorg/ubuntu-desktop - dist-upgrade - Re-install xorg/ubuntu-desktop**
I tried fixes like as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053905):
1- remove xorg
2- dist-upgrade
3- install ubuntu-desktop

**and [disabled the wayland](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086935)**
1- disabled wayland in gdm3 custom.conf

Currently, I am running on xorg configuration and I am still feeling that experience is bit laggy. I am suspecting that it might be issue with Core M processor or I need to install the correct drivers.

I need community input on this as to have some pointers to move forward with experiments.

Comment: so, to be clear you're not interested in using 19.04? you only want LTS versions?

Comment: Yes. I learned that there are some fixes in Gnome 3.30.x releases but 19.04 support will end in July. Therefore not going for 19.04 right now. Will upgrade to Ubuntu 20.x LTS next year.

Comment: good idea :) I would advise it