# Check Resolution to 18.04 gdm3 Issue

Tags: boot, 18.04, lightdm, gdm, bug-reporting

After a recent software update my computer stopped booting into the normal login screen. Instead I see several terminal logs that ends with

`Started User Manager for UID 120`

Or something like this

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 gdm3 login]

I read in a few places that I needed to uncomment `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. This did not work for me.

I then installed and configured `lightdm` based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037192/60869) and now my computer boots into a black screen, but after I [move my mouse](https://plus.google.com/103376841046342900336/posts/YpQCqPeVVFe) a bit or hold the shift key during boot the login screen appears and I’m successfully able to login.

I’m hoping a future software update will bring things back to ‘normal’. Ideally I’d like to revert back to `gdm3` and have the default 18.04 login experience.

Right now I’ve subscribed to updates to what [might be](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1768041) [the bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1727356) in launchpad. I also try and boot using `gdm3` with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` after software updates now and then. Is there a better way to check if this issue is resolved?

My computer's [hardware information is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OYbtPsStfsPo7tGxFPOdHt7-iI3J-9bu) if that's useful to know.

Comment: Provide info on your system and graphics card because that may also be at the base of the issue.

Comment: @vanadium I've added a link to my hardware information in the question.