# 18.04 Error while booting. Hangs on line "stopping user manager for uid 123"

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04, login, lightdm

My sisters main computer is having major problems booting up and I cant quite figure it out. During boot it hangs on line "stopping user manager for uid 123".

I have done both `sudo dpkg-configure lightdm` as well as editing the custom.conf file by using command `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and then unmarking the 'WaylandEnable=false' line.

Still nothing. I removed her nvidia graphics card and ran the `sudo dpkg-configure lightdm` line again.  This seems to fix the problem for most people. Booting up shows me a blank screen. After pressing CTRL+ALT+F4 I begin to type her login and then the regular Ubuntu login appears out of no where. At least she can use her computer right now but its a pain to get it to the regular logon screen. Ive ran all updates and everything is updated and seems great otherwise.

Any tips or commands I could do to solve these issues? Ultimately Id like to get her computer working again with the nvidia card in it since she plays games like WoW (worldofwarcraft).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Some great tips here, but nothing helped my situation... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot/1037192#1037192

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F3 and/or CTRL+ALT+F5 gets me to the login screen. So at least I can get there and log in. Now need help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I backed up all her important data, wiped 18.04 off and installed 16.04 and ran all updates. Everything is working gloriously now.

She had been using 16.04 the past couple years and she wanted to update to 18.04... its been working fine for her the past month or two until this issue came about. She is much happier using 16.04 again.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `lightdm` the `nomodeset` parameter was the key to fixing my issue with 18.04

#### Nomodeset: How to get in once via temporary grub change

You can add the grub configuration parameters if you hold right `shift` at bootup and press `e` to edit Ubuntu parameters.  You need to replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.  Then hit `ctrl x` to save and continue.

#### Lightdm: How to put in the permanent fix

Once in, open a terminal and type
`sudo apt install lightdm`, then
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, then
`sudo reboot`

Please refer to this amazing guide for more details and screenshots!:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)