# Upgrade to 18,04 -- Blank Screen

Tags: 18.04, configuration

After upgrade from 16.02LTS to 18.04LTS, I get the Ubuntu .... screen and then blank with possibly a slightly different color.
Booting in recovery mode and selecting option to continue in default graphics there is a box on screen that says the screen, graphics card, and input device settings can not be detected and I need to configure them myself.  How can I accomplish this?
I have looked at similar ?'s and nothing offered there even mentions configuring the options manually.   The possible duplicate of 17.10 to 18.04 may be applicable but the number of different steps/changes mentioned don't seem applicable.

Adding nomodeset in the grub command makes no difference except that after the Ubuntu splash shows, it drops to a terminal-like display with commands beginning with [OK] and eventually hangs.  I may be able to select the root option from the recovery menu and use it to try to update the i915 drivers.  But at this point I may just throw in the towel and admit that 5 year old hardware that worked with 14 and 16 just might not be compatible with 18.

Comment: in the boot menu, select advanced boot options and add "nomodeset" or "acpi=off" to the end of the first boot line: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: also, let us know what video card you have,  run `sudo lshw -C display` and edit question to include the output... this can be done in recovery mode if above comment doesn't get system booted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) and [17.10 to 18.04 upgrade freezes during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot)

Comment: Output from lshw -C display           *-display UNCLAIMED
 description: VGA compatible controller
 product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
 vendor: Intel Corporation
 physical id: 2
 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.9
 version: 09
 width: 64bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
 configuration: latency=0
 resources: memory:f780000-f7bfffff memory:e000000-efffffff ioport:f00(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff