# Wrong graphics resolution after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: display-resolution, intel

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and got a wrong graphics resolution. I tried to add a correct resolution manually but this does not work. I have integrated graphics card Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 running on MS-A923. Possibly, this is connected with errors found in Xorg.0.log:

```
(EE) No devices detected.
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
(EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
(EE) event5  - IDEACO  IDC 6681: libinput bug: missing tablet capabilities: btn      
stylus resolution.Ignoring this device.
(EE) libinput: IDEACO  IDC 6681: Failed to create a device for /dev/input/event5
(EE) PreInit returned 2 for "IDEACO  IDC 6681"
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

**Update #1**

After checking Xorg.0.log:

```
(II) VESA(0): clock: 72.0 MHz   Image Size:  410 x 230 mm
(II) VESA(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1380  h_sync_end 1436      h_blank_end 1500 h_border: 0
(II) VESA(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 769  v_sync_end 772 v_blanking: 800 v_border: 0
```

I think that the graphics driver finds a correct mode, but for some reason the correct monitor resolution is not found:

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1366x768
```

outputs: `xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 1366x768)`

**Update #2**

Fresh install did not help. I was unable to install 18.04 in graphic mode (again, the installation shows just background and mouse). Text mode would probably help, but I was unsure if I would get working GUI. Therefore, I returned back to 16.04, which works fine (after some manipulation with display setting menu, disabling built-in display). Thanks @heynnema for your support!

Comment: Open **Software & Updates** and click on the **Additional Drivers** tab, and see if a video driver is enabled there. Or review **Update #7** at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot)

Comment: I opened **Additional Drivers**, but nothing appeared there. But the `microcode` is loaded. **Update #7** did not help in my case.

Comment: At the gear icon on your login screen, try setting your environment to **Ubuntu** or **Ubuntu on xorg/X11**. Otherwise you might need a custom X11.conf file, but I can't help with that. Anything beyond that and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I also tried this (and a complete reinstall of xorg) but nothing works.

Comment: You don't happen to have **nomodeset** in your kernel boot line do you?

Comment: Bingo! But now the X shows just the background (and mouse) and `lightdm` freezes completely. But I have seen this, so I hope that with some googling...

Comment: Disable all GNOME shell extensions [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) , and try **sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm**. Report back to @heynnema. If that'all works, I'll write an answer that you can accept, if it was at all helpful.

Comment: I think that I do not have any GNOME shell extensions installed (at least `sudo apt list --installed | grep gnome-shell-extensions` does not show anything) and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` leads to the same result as with `gdm3` (`lightdm` works as `gdm3` after deleting `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`).

Comment: You incorrectly checked for GNOME extensions. Click on "here" in my previous comment. Replace /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with the original file. You need it. Also, please summarize where we are... I've lost track on what's happening now.

Comment: With `nomodeset` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` the system boots in low resolution, but `gdm3` works fine. Without `nomodeset` the systems boots in high resolution, but `gdm3` and `lightdm` provide just background and mouse. Solutions like reinstalling xorg and renaming `.config` do not work. Sorry, I have forgotten to mention that the link gives just "GNOME Shell Extensions cannot list your installed extensions." and "To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration...".

Comment: It's probably your video driver that's causing your problem. nomodeset should not be used, except to troubleshoot. You must have had it there before the 18.04 upgrade... surprising that you didn't notice a problem before. The GNOME extension link will give you those errors if you haven't properly installed the software to support viewing/managing your GNOME extensions. Follow the instructions to install the required software, and retry the link to check your installed extensions... any of which could cause some of your problems.

Comment: I installed suggested packages of GNOME extensions. Now the page shows two extensions, which are OFF.

Comment: That's good. Go to **Software & Updates** and click the **Additional Drivers** tab, and see if it has a video driver, and if it's enabled. What video subsystem are you running with... Nvidia? Also, make sure that you've selected the correct display manager environment on the login screen... the little cogwheel.

Comment: I included nomodeset after upgrade (to get some display). There are no items in **Additional Drivers**. Sorry, I do not understand the question about the video subsystem. I am using i915 driver, although `sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration` shows `configuration: latency=0`, and i915 is running according to `lsmod`. I am using **Ubuntu** display manager environment, but in high-res the login screen does not appear (just a blank screen with a mouse). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lets try to eliminate a wayland problem that effects older computers. Edit **/etc/gdm3/custom.conf** and uncomment **#WaylandEnable=false**. I know that you've done this before, but that was when nomodeset was enabled. Make sure that you use the **sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3** command and select gdm3.

Comment: If that doesn't work, boot to a 18.04 live DVD and reinstall 18.04 over the existing 18.04.

Comment: Yes, **#WaylandEnable=false** is uncommented. So it looks like reinstall...