# Purple screen freeze while first use(cant open terminal or grub menu)

Tags: boot, 18.04, freeze

I installed ubuntu I can login but after login a purple screen apears Ican move cursor but I cant do anything else.I cant open terminal when I am at login screen or later. And I cant open GNU grub menu with shift key. I tried elemantary os and deepin too. I can use terminal  when I am at login screen in elementsry os and deepin.I tried sudo add-apt-get....(I cant remember but it is about nvidia driver) but it did not worked. It said cant find command.I use a notebook with I7-7700hq intel graphics and nvidia gtx 1050ti. I really want to use linux but I cant I tried almost everything please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [17.10 to 18.04 upgrade freezes during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot)