# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 hangs at deb cdrom

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I have a HP 15 ac650tu laptop. The laptop has Windows 10 installed and is working fine.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04, using a bootable USB drive. 
Initially I faced an ACPI error. After checking on web, I resolved it by setting acpi=off.

Now after running with acpi=off option, the Ubuntu hangs at the error below.

```
Writing new source list
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set
```

Comment: Have you verfied the ISO? Try this: Before disk partitioning press: ALT+F3, press: ENTER,  type: `ln -s /cdrom/ /media/cdrom` and press: ENTER, press ALT+F1 to comeback to GUI.

Comment: I have tried the bootable usb on a different laptop and I was able to install ubuntu 18.04 on it. So i guess the ISO should be okay. I the above case, I am not able to go even to the Try ubuntu without install option.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. Hopefully someone else can help you out.

Comment: After a bit of googling, I switched off fast boot in windows. Now the installation hangs at: Started user manager 999. I have intel integrated graphics and no external graphics card.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086935) might help