# Ubuntu 18.04 requires multiple attempts to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I have a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation on a Thinkpad W520 (16GB, Intel® Core™ i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz, Nvidia Quadro 1000M):

- Windows 7 on `sda` (original Win boot loader)
- Ubuntu on `sdb` (Linux boot loader installed on `sdb5`)

Since the beginning, I have to do at least 3 attempts before managing to boot Ubuntu. After searching a while for a solution, I installed the latest drivers. It didn't solved the problem. Now I have one of the following random outcome when trying to boot the system:

1. Blank screen (same dark purple color as Ubuntu's grub)
2. Black black screen
3. Black screen with cursor on top left
4. Screen stuck on this message:

   ```
   /dev/sdb5: recovering journal
   /dev/sdb5: clean, 233651/30531584 files, 5941895/122094848 blocks
   ```
5. Message as in (4) flashes for a while, then the system boots
6. Systems boots regularly

Now that Ubuntu finally has booted, I'm examining the logs.
I found the message:

```bsh
ott 05 11:48:01 enea-ThinkPad-W520 nvidia-persistenced[790]: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 122 has read and write permissions for those files.
```

I can't figure out how to solve it. Now that the system has booted, the graphic card seems to work perfectly. However, if I try to reboot the system, again I have a 2 out of 3 chances it won't boot at all...

Attachments:

- [My journalctl log](https://pastebin.com/KtpDeDvx)
- [Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/u5SqEHCP)
- [Xorg.1.log](https://pastebin.com/Zd1VbCNh)

**UPDATE:**
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot) I found the suggestion to set `WaylandEnable=false` in my `gdm3/custom.conf`. Elsewhere I found this should solve the issue due to an bug that occurs with the NVidia driver on older CPUs. Trying this change and rebooting again... Keeping my fingers crossed...

**EDIT:**
Nothing changed after the previous suggestion. I only had to tried twice before being able to boot the system, but the problem is still there. I'm out of options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found an answer to my own problem.

Apparently there is a [well known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/776999) that affects Lenovo Thinkpads with accelerated graphic card. Sometimes it's even impossible to boot the system just after a fresh installation.

I found [here a workaround](https://gist.github.com/wbond/3800562) for Fedora that works well with Ubuntu, too.